# Mapping CSV column to POJO class when using Super CSV

Tags: java, csv, annotations, supercsv

I need to map a CSV column name to a POJO class in JAVA. But the names in the CSV files and Java classes are a little different. Also, I don't need all columns in the CSV files to be mapped to POJOs, I only need certain columns. Tried mapping using column name.

But the below implementation only works only if the CSV column names and POJO class field names match.

I am using Super CSV for my implementation. Any annotations/ways to handle this [different names in POJO fields / CSV columns], I am really stuck here.

**Code**:

```java
ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
Employee employee;
//columns to be mapped
final List<String> columnsToMap = Arrays.asList("emp_id_no", "emp_name", "emp_dept");

HashMap<String, Object> employeeMap;
try {

    beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),
            new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).build());

    // read the CSV header (and set any unwanted columns to null)
    String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
        if (!columnsToMap.contains(header[i])) {
            header[i] = null;
        }
    }

    for (String s: header) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    
    employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    while ((employee = beanReader.read(Employee.class, header)) != null) {
        System.out.println(employee);
    }
}
```

**csv**:

```
emp_id,emp_name,emp_phone_no,emp_dept,emp_address_details
1,"abc","finance",123,"hgdhgede"
2,"def","hr",456,"dwnhffjefnv"
```

**POJO** will be:

```java
public class Employee {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int empId;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String empName;
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String empDept;
}
```

Comment: Did you try  **@SerializedName("column_name")** annotation ?

Comment: No, let me try now

Comment: but @VikasChoudhary, we can use above annotations only for JSON related stuffs right

Comment: its not working Vikas, need to check some other ways. Thanks!

Comment: Yes It is related to JSON but I thought it should work. I am sorry I commented before actually making sure it will work or not. It was the first thought came after reading your question. I will look for other solutions and get back to you if I find anything rigid. Thanks for understanding. :)